# Communication between worker threads

Tags: android, multithreading, communication

I am programming in Android environment, and I have in my project a Main Activity, in which there is an AsynkTask class, and separately a Thread object, realized extending Runnable interface. Now, AsynkTask and the Thread can be seen as two worker threads managed by the main thread, that is the Main Activity. How can I do if I want to make possible the communication between the two worker threads, not involving the main thread? How can I use handlers to realize this? I know how to use handlers between main and worker threads. I want to know how use them only between the worker threads, because in this case I can't pass in constructors handlers, because in this case I can not directly instantiate a thread, passing it as a parameter the handler created by the main thread. The main thread must create two worker threads, and they must communicate without the involvement of the main thread.
I hope I have been clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a Handler with a worker thread you have to create a Looper on that Thread as explained in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html.

Like this:

```
 class LooperThread extends Thread {
      public Handler mHandler;

      public void run() {
          Looper.prepare();

          mHandler = new Handler() {
              public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                  // process incoming messages here
              }
          };

          Looper.loop();
      }
  }
```

And then you can send messages to `mHandler` from any other `Thread`.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer. Ok,I can create this Handler in one of the two worker threads. But how can I receive the message in the other?

Comment: I would create a Handler in each of the worker threads, what prevents you from doing so?

Comment: I thought it was necessary for the communication between two worker threads, that the handler created by one was passed as a parameter in the constructor of the other, and this is my problem, since the main thread instantiates the two worker threads, and when it does this, it does not know the handler created by one to pass it as input to another.

Comment: No, you can just send mThread.mHandler.send(mHandler.obtainMessage())